# Linux booting only sometimes

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, luks

I used a Notebook with a proper working MX Linux installation (LUKS encrypted disk, GRUB bootloader). This Notebook died, but i could get hands on the exact same model and hardware configuration.

So i took the NVMe SSD from the broken Notebook and plugged it into the new one, where i created a boot entry in BIOS for the `\MX\grubx64.efi` file - and  *sometimes* it's really working fine.

**What always works:**

I power up the Notebook, it's performing the initial startup. Then it displays

```
MX 21.3 Wildflower booting
Loading Linux 5.10.0-23-amd64...
Loading initial ramdisk...
```

**What should happen next always, but doesn't:**

There is a short time of screen flickering, just for a second or two. Then the prompt is shown to enter the password for the encrypted disk. After that's entered, MX starts.

**What does happen if it's not working:**

After `Loading initial ramdisk...`, the screen turns black and freezes there, nothing else happens.

**What i do then:**

If the startup process is stuck like this, i hold the power button just killing it. Then i press it again to start the Notebook. I do that as many times as it's needed. Sometimes, the OS loads just fine multiple times - sometimes, i have to restart the stuck boot process many times before it's starting up normally.

**What i already tried:**

I tried every possible boot configuration in BIOS, but that didn't solve the problem. As there is always shown that MX Linux is loaded, i think the BIOS boot settings are allright.

I guess the problem lies within the SSD and itself (bootloader? crypt setup? just guessing) and has to do with the hardware change, but i have no clue where to look for this issue.

*Edit: Updated title and question to clarify the issue*

Comment: *Pro Tip:* If you know a notification is going to go by too fast to read, film it on your phone, then you can pause the playback.

Comment: If the new notebook came with a disk, does it boot ok from it?

Comment: @harrymc: It came with a disk, but i honestly never tested it by myself now - as i know the previous owner was using he notebook regulary with its disk (Windows 10) and would have come to me, if there were any problem like this.

Comment: This raises the possibility that the disk from the crashed computer is damaged. Going further, it might even be that the old computer is fine and the problem was all along just with the disk.

Comment: @harrymc: As the screen of the old notebook lies shattered in the trash, because i broke it, i'm pretty sure it wasn't just a hard drive failure. The notebook didn't drop, i just managed to kill its screen. Because i could get the same model without hassle, i didn't look for replacing the screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thank you very much, i will do this when i reboot. I am almost sure the very short displayed text is identical, both when the boot process is successful and when it isn't. But i will check that.

Comment: In addition to the possibility that disk is bad, other possibilities are a problem with the new computer, or that some BIOS settings are not suitable for your boot disk.

Comment: @harrymc: A general failure might be possible, but unlikely, as the boot process always recognizes the bootimage like the mentioned short text states. Also, if a boot configuration would be the problem - why would it work by simply restarting, without changing it? Somehow i guess it's more a problem of the crypted disk setup and the hardware change, after the BIOS boot.

Comment: First plausible thing to do in this situation would be to check and update the BIOS / Firmware of the new system. Such "unpredictable" behavior can be triggered by errors in BIOS. The error seems to occur when the UEFI passes the control to the OS. As you are using Linux  in contrast to the previous user using Windows, it is plausible that he might not have been bothered by this problem.

Comment: @dodrg: I just updated the title and question to clarify. The linux bootloader is loaded every time - but sometimes it's stuck. As the grub efi is always recognized, i don't think it's a BIOS issue?

Comment: I think I've seen something similar caused by configuration based on `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` (or `nvme…` or `mmcblk…` etc.) instead of UUIDs or so. When disks were enumerated in the "wrong" order, the OS could not boot. This was without LUKS though, I don't know LUKS. Anyway, in your new notebook, is there an extra NVMe SSD that can cause such race condition?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: No, there is no second disk, just the one i inserted - but your comment makes me wonder if this disk might now have other identifiers than in the old notebook, and if that might cause the issue? But... how to check that?

Comment: Well, even if your hypothesis is right, I guess since there is just one block device now, the config should be always OK or always bad, *not sometimes*. It may be reasonable to check if the default entry in `grub.cfg` bases on an UUID; but frankly I really doubt the scenario from my previous comment can happen in case of just one block device.

Answer (score 0):

**For future readers:**

i could **not** solve this problem.

It had nothing to do with the notebook or its BIOS. The system on the swapped disk was broken way beyond repair.

I still don't know how all this could have happened.

Some guys over at the MX linux forum, the system i used, really tried hard to help me make it work again, but in the end, things got worse and no rescue attempt could help.

After a few days of trying to fix this system, i went with re-installing it from scratch.

I already had a backup of the important data and using a live linux system i could even save my `/home` directory of the broken system installation.

Lesson learned: Even "just" a switch of the disk could do serious damage to the system on it.

Backup you data, folks.

Another thing users of MX linux should note: This system has a very good snapshot tool - use it. If i had a snapshot of my system, re-installing it would be a matter of a few mouse clicks and minutes and i would have my setup back as it was. Now, i have to re-configure a lot of things, as i had only data-backups, not system ones.

Maybe this is helpful for anyone stumbling upon this.